# How to combine files with ";"

Tags: multiple-columns

I have two text files. One file has a list of names, and the second file has a list of phone numbers. I'd like to create a file with `name;phonenumber`. Any idea how I can combine the two files?

File 1 has 20k+ entries with names. File 2 has 20k+ entries with the corresponding phone number. I'd like the new file to be:

```
name1;phone1;
name2;phone2;
```

I am using Notepad++.

Comment: Did you try a web search with the terms "combine files with notepad++"?

Comment: Is it `name;phonenumber` or `name;phonenumber;`? `;` at the end of each line or just as column separator? What platform are you on? Do you have access to Linux coreutils such as `cut`?